# function OffLineMinimum(strArr) (Coderbyte exercise #30)

Tags: javascript

> Using the JavaScript language, have the `function
>   OffLineMinimum(strArr)` take the `strArr` parameter being passed which
>   will be an array of integers ranging from 1...n and the letter "E" and
>   return the correct subset based on the following rules.
>
> The input will be in the following format:
>   `["I","I","E","I",...,"E",...,"I"]` where the I's stand for integers
>   and the E means take out the smallest integer currently in the whole
>   set.
>
> When finished, your program should return that new set with integers
>   separated by commas.
>
> For example: if `strArr` is
>   `["5","4","6","E","1","7","E","E","3","2"]` then your program should
>   return `4,1,5`.

I am a new learner in JS.

1. I don't really understand the question.
2. I've did some research on other answers. For example, this one below. 
   https://github.com/ratracegrad/coderbyte-Beginner/blob/master/Off%20Line%20Minimium#L42
   Can you walk me through it?
3. Any suggestion or better solution for a beginner? Like how to write a pseudo code for this or how I can proceed when reading a question like this?

Thank you for taking your time reading this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, I would use [dichotomic searches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search) to insert the numbers in `strArr` to an ordered array. When `"E"` is found, instead of inserting, the first number in the sorted array is removed and pushed to the result array.

```js
var insertInOrderedArr = function f(arr, item, from=0, to=arr.length) {
  if(from === to) return arr.splice(to, 0, item);
  var mid = Math.floor((from + to) / 2);
  if(arr[mid] > item) return f(arr, item, from, mid);
  if(arr[mid] < item) return f(arr, item, mid+1, to);
  return f(arr, item, mid, mid);
}
function offLineMinimum(strArr) {
  var sorted = [],
      result = [];
  for(var item of strArr) {
    if(item === "E") result.push(sorted.shift());
    else insertInOrderedArr(sorted, +item);
  }
  return result;
}
```